# Python: SVG to PNG converting issue

Tags: python, svg, reportlab

**UPDATE:** I tried increasing size in the chess.svg.board and it somehow cleared all the rendering issues at size = <del>900</del> 1800 
I tried using the svglib and reportlab to make .png files from .svg, and here is how the code looks:

```py
import sys
import chess.svg
import chess
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM

board = chess.Board("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR")

drawing = chess.svg.board(board, size=350)
f = open('file.svg', 'w')
f.write(drawing)

drawing = svg2rlg("file.svg")
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "file.png", fmt="png")
```

If you try to open file.png there is a lot of missing parts of the image, which i guess are rendering issues. How can you fix this?
Sidenote: also getting a lot of 'x_order_2: colinear!' messages when running this on a discord bot, but I am not sure if this affects anything yet.
[image]

Comment: This appears to be an issue with Reportlab 3.5.60; there's a bug report [here](https://pairlist2.pair.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2021-January/012034.html).  Perhaps try a newer or older version?

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up solving it by instead using the cairo renderer (via [cairosvg Python package](https://cairosvg.org/)), which doesn't exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS!! I am having the same error with the same libraries... I didn't find a solution but just a workaround which probably won't help too much in your case, where the shapes generating the bands are not very sparse vertically.

I'll try playing with the file dimensions too, but so far this is what I got. Note that my svg consists of black shapes on a white background (hence the `255 - x` in the following code)

Since the appearance of the bands is extremely random, and processing the same file several times in a row produces different results, I decided to take advantage of randomness: what I do is I export the same svg a few times into different pngs, import them all into a list and then only take those pixels that are white in all the exported images, something like:

```
images_files = [my_convert_function(svgfile=file, index=i) for i in range(3)]
images = [255 - imageio.imread(x) for x in images_files]
result = reduce(lambda a,b: a & b, images)
imageio.imwrite(<your filename here>, result)
[os.remove(x) for x in images_files]
```

where `my_convert_function` contains your same `svg2rlg` and `renderPM.drawToFile`, and returns the name of the png file being written. The index 'i' is to save several copies of the same png with different names.

It's some very crude code but I hope it can help other people with the same issue

Answer (score -3):

The format parameter has to be in uppercase

```
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "file.png", fmt="PNG")
```

Comment: Sadly this did not change anything for me. The image came out exactly the same as before.

Comment: I am also running my code on replit if that makes any difference (updates and versions)